# how to know current internet connection run on device?

Tags: android, connection, 3g

i want know the current internet connection on device??

in android i found the two property to know network type like..

> ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
>
> ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE

but how to know 3G network??

pls help me out

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

now i can know 3 type of network as follow..........

> ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>
> android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
>
> android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
>
> NetworkInfo info = connec.getActiveNetworkInfo();
>
> int netSubType = info.getSubtype();e
>
> ```
>             if (wifi.isConnected()) 
>             {
>
>              wifi is connected
>
>             }
>             else if (mobile.isConnected())
>             {
> ```

```
                if(netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS)
                {   
                       3G is connected

                }
                else
                {
                      GPRS is connected

                }


            }
```

Answer (score 5):

try to get `subType()` with this snippet:

```
NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int netSubType = info.getSubtype();
```

then if `netSubType` is `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS`, then its a 3G network

*Updated: What's 'info' here*

Comment: dude can you tell me what is that info , i tried ConnectivityManager its not working..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used 3G is coming under `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` only.

If you are using emulator then you can press F8 to connect and disconnect 3G.

It also disconnects GPRS. for both `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` is used.